# Advanced Warfare: The KVA escapes this the hostage. ("Traffic" mission)

Tags: call-of-duty-advanced-warfare

I just starting playing Advanced Warfare a couple of days ago and I had to get off today, when I get back on I spawn doing the part where you have the date take down the chopper. I spawn far up in the ocean and it says "Take down the enemy chopper. I try to do that and I get it to go on fire and its heading towards the water and Gideon says "Jump!" So I jump and I turn around and he getting smooshed by a semi. It says that "The KVA escaped with the hostage." And I have to restart the mission at the same place and this happens over and over again. Can anyone help me I don't know what's going on.

Comment: There's a guide to the mission here:
http://www.ign.com/wikis/call-of-duty-advanced-warfare/Traffic ;sounds like you're having trouble here " After it catches fire, jump immediately to the next bus that appears, ***then another just after*** and leapfrog your way to the truck. "